# Loading Parquet and Delta files into Azure Synapse using ADB or Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, databricks, parquet, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I have a below case scenario.

We are using Azure Databricks to pull data from several sources and generate the Parquet and Delta files and loaded them into our ADLS Gen2 Containers.

We are now planning to create our data warehouse inside Azure Synapse SQL Pools, where we will create external tables for dimension tables which will use delta files and hash distributed fact tables using Parquet files.

Now, the question is, to automate this data warehousing loading activity, which method is better? Is it better to use Azure Databricks to write our transformation logic to create dim and fact tables and load them regularly inside Azure Synapse SQL pools (or) is it better to use Azure Synapse to write our transformation logic to create dim and fact tables and load them regularly inside Azure Synapse SQL pools.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already having your setup in Azure synapse analytics. You can consider writing your transformations using Azure Synapse analytics. As synapse analytics will also have a metadata sharing it would be easy between spark pools and SQL pools

Benefits I see if you are making them in Azure Synapse are:

1. You can use the same transformations that you used in databricks in Azure synapse analytics using Spark pools.
2. Maintenance would be easy as everything will go in single service.
3. No need to worry about authentication issues between services